# Why does not the Montel Theorem apply in this case?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I have proved that the family is not equicontinuous, but it is not understanding why the theorem 3.3 can not be applied. Can someone explain me?

Comment: Probably because $\sin(nx)$ is not holomorphic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because if we take any open set $A$ in the complex plane such that $(0,1)\subset A$ then $A$ must have an element $z=a+bi$ with $b\neq 0.$
Therefore $|\sin nz|=|(2i)^{-1} (e^{nia -nb} -e^{-nia +nb})|\to \infty $ as $n\to \infty.$
So the family is not uniformly bounded in any region $A$ in complex plane, such that $(0,1)\subset A.$

Comment: The book itself says that the family is uniformly limited, do not you think it can be something else? Being uniformly limited does not refer to the open containing the set, but to the compacts that are contained in the set.

Comment: In the theorem $\Omega$ is an open subset of the plane. If  $\Omega$ is an open subset of the plane and $(0,1)\subset\Omega$ then there exists a compact $K\subset \Omega$ such that $\\sin(nz)$ is not uniformly bounded on $K$. That's clear from the above, since singletons are compact.